# Efficient & Pythonic way of finding all possible sublists of a list in given range and the minimum product after multipying all elements in them?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, reduce

**I've achived these two things.**

1. Find all possible sublists of a list in given range `(i ,j)`.

   ```
   A = [ 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 11, 22, 33 ] 
   Let, i = 2 and j = 4
   ```

   Then, Possible sublists of the list `"A"` in the given range `(2,4)` is :

   ```
   [66], [66,77], [66,77,88], [77], [77,88], [88]
   ```
2. And, minimum of the resultant product after multipying all the elements of the sublists: 

   So, the resultant list after multiplying all the elements in the above sublists will become

   ```
   X = [66, 5082, 447216, 77, 6776, 88]`
   ```

   Now, the minimum of the above list, which is `min(X)` i.e `66`

**My Code**:

```
i, j = 2, 4
A = [ 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 11, 22, 33 ] 
O, P = i, i
mini = A[O]
while O <= j and P <= j:
    if O == P:
        mini = min(mini, reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [A[O]]))
    else:
        mini = min(mini, reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, A[O:P + 1]))
    P += 1
    if P > j:
        O += 1
        P = O
print(mini)
```

**My Question:**

This code is taking more time to get executed for the Larger Lists and Larger Ranges ! 
 Is there any possible "Pythonic" way of reducing the time complexity of the above code ? 
 Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

Got it. But, If there is more than one such possible sublist with the same minimum product,

1. I need the longest sub list range `(i,j)`
2. If there are still more than one sublists with the same "longest sub range", I need to print the sub-interval which has the lowest start index.

Consider this list `A = [2, 22, 10, 12, 2]` if `(i,j) = (0,4)`. 
There is a tie. `Min product = 2` with two possibilities `'(0,0)' and '(4,4)'` . 
 Both sub list range = 0 `[ (0-0) and (4-4) ]` 
In this case i need to `print (minproduct, [sublist-range])` =  `2, [0,0]`

Tried using dictionaries, It works for some inputs but not for all ! How to do this 'efficiently' ? 
Thank you !

Comment: What's the possible range of the elements in the list? Like are they positive? Are they integers?

Comment: @YuHao, Yes.. positive Integers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, given the list and the index range, we can get the sublist `A[i : j + 1]`

```
[66, 77, 88]
```

For positive integers `a` and `b`, `a * b` is no less than `a` or `b`. So you don't need to do multiplying, it's not possible that multiplying of two or more elements has a smaller result. The minimum of this list *is* the minimum of all the  multiplying results.

So the result is:

```
min(A[i : j + 1])
```

Comment: Thank you sir, If there is more than one such possible sublist with the same minimum product, How to get the longest sublist (long sub range) ?

Comment: @Srikanth Assuming `a` and `b` are positive integers, `a * b` equals to `a` only if `b` is `1`. So to get the longest such sublists, find `1`s.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, this is correct

Answer (score 3):

For generating the sublists, it is as simple as two nested `for` loops in a list comprehension:

```
def sublists(l,i,j):
    return [l[m:n+1] for m in range(i,j+1) for n in range(m,j+1)]
```

example:

```
>>> sublists(A,2,4)
[[66], [66, 77], [66, 77, 88], [77], [77, 88], [88]]
```

For finding the minimum product:

```
>>> min(map(prod, sublists(A,2,4)))
66
```

(you import `prod` from `numpy`, or define it as `def prod(x): return reduce(lambda i,j:i*j,x)`)

Comment: To make your answer more clear, could you please add what the `i` and `j` arguments in `sublists` do?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct for all positive ints as you cannot multiply the smallest element by any number and get a smaller result. It might make more sense if you were getting  all the slices greater than length 1.

If you were going to calculate it then you could use `itertools.islice` to get each slice and get the min using a generator expression:

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import mul

print(min(reduce(mul, islice(A, n, k + 1), 1)
          for n in range(i, j + 1) for k in range(n, j + 1)))

66
```

If for i = 0 and j = 4 you considered `(44, 55, 66, 88)` a legitimate slice then you would need to use itertools.combinations.

Answer (score 1):

**#EDIT: Quick Solution:**

```
min(A[i:j+1])
```

Since all the numbers are positive integers, and you want to find the minimum product of all possible sublists of `A[i:j+1]` list
slice, it will also contain sublists of length 1. **The minimum products of all such sublists will be lowest number among the `A[i:j+1]` slice.**

**Another Solution:**

The below method will be useful when you need **to find the maximum product of sublists or you need all the possible combinations of `A[i:j+1]` list slice.**

We'll use [**itertools.combinations**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to solve this. We can do this in 3 steps.

**Step1: Get the slice of the list**

```
my_list = A[i:j+1]
```

This will give us the slice to work on.

```
my_list = A[2:5]
my_list
[66, 77, 88]
```

**Step-2 Generate all possible combinations:**

```
import itertools

my_combinations = []

for x in range(1, len(my_list)+1):
    my_combinations.extend(list(itertools.combinations(my_list,x)))

my_combinations
[(66,), (77,), (88,), (66, 77), (66, 88), (77, 88), (66, 77, 88)]
```

> iterools.combinations returns r length subsequences of elements from
>   the input iterable

So, we will use this to generate subsequences of length 1 to length equal to length of `my_list`. We will get a list of tuples with each element being a subsequence.

**Step-3 : Find min product of all possible combinations**

```
products_list = [reduce(lambda i,j:i*j, x) for x in my_combinations]
[66, 77, 88, 5082, 5808, 6776, 447216]

min(products_list)
66
```

After getting the subsequences, we apply list comprehension along with `reduce()` to get the list of products for all the subsequences in `my_combinations` list. Then we apply `min()` function to get the minimum product out of the `products_list` which will give us our answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a `itertools.combinations()`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Call it passing the sublist, in a loop, with the other parameter varying from 1 to the length of the sublist.

It will definitely take "more time to get executed for the Larger Lists and Larger Ranges", i think that's inevitable. But might be much faster than your approach. Measure and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(a_list):

    sub = [[]]

    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        for j in range(len(a_list)):
            if(i == j):
                sub.append([a_list[i]])
            elif(i > j):
                sub.append([a_list[j],a_list[i]])
    sub.append(a_list)
    return sub


solution([10, 20, 30])
```

---

```
[[], [10], [10, 20], [20], [10, 30], [20, 30], [30], [10, 20, 30]]
```